# delete file with name --help.tgz

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I have file with name `--help.tgz`. I want to delete but don't know how.
I tried `rm "--help.tgz"`, `rm \-\-help.tgz` and it did not work. How can I delete a file with such name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `rm -- --help.tgz`

The `--` tells `rm` that there are no further flags to process and that everything else are the files/directories to be deleted.  Most unix utilities use -- in a similar way.